# JPA : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException while persisting a Map<Entity,Entity>

Tags: java, generics, jpa, eclipselink

I have an abstract base class like this and want to persist the map `myMap` of a subclass.

```
public abstract class MyGenericAbstractClass<V, E> {

Map<E, SomeClass<V>> myMap;

public Map<E, SomeClass<V>> getMyMap() {
    return myMap;
}
```

As I can't annotate the generic map in the abstract base class(as JPA needs to have the type information for table creation), I decided to override the getter in the the subclass and go for property access.

```
@Entity
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class MyGenericClass extends MyGenericAbstractClass<VImpl, EImpl> {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

  @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
  @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
  @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "EIMPL_ID")
  @JoinTable(name = "MapName")
  @Override
  public Map<EImpl, SomeClass<VImpl>> getMyMap() {
    return myMap;
  }

}
```

`SomeClass.java` looks like this right now :

```
@Entity
public class SomeClass<V> {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

@OneToOne(targetEntity = jpa.test.minimalExample.VImpl.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
V source;

@OneToOne(targetEntity = jpa.test.minimalExample.VImpl.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
V target;

}
```

Main:

```
EntityManagerFactory factory =   Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Minimal");
EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();         
em.getTransaction().begin();

MyGenericClass mgc = new MyGenericClass();
SomeClass<VImpl> bar = new SomeClass<VImpl>();
EImpl foo = new EImpl();
Map<EImpl,SomeClass<VImpl>> mgcMap = new HashMap<EImpl,SomeClass<VImpl>>();    

mgcMap.put(foo, bar);
mgc.setMyMap(mgcMap);

em.persist(foo);
em.persist(mgc);        
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

`EImpl` and `VImpl` are pretty much nearly empty Entities (just the id).

persistence.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
      version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
      <persistence-unit name="Minimal" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>    

    <class>jpa.test.minimalExample.SomeClass</class>
    <class>jpa.test.minimalExample.MyGenericClass</class>
    <class>jpa.test.minimalExample.MyGenericAbstractClass</class>
    <class>jpa.test.minimalExample.VImpl</class>
    <class>jpa.test.minimalExample.EImpl</class>


 <properties>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver" />
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"  value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/simpleTest/;create=true" />
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="test" />
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="test" />

  <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables" />
  <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database" />
 </properties>

  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Finally, this is the error I get:

> [EL Warning]: 2016-05-27
>   13:55:12.675--UnitOfWork(674882504)--Exception [EclipseLink-26]
>   (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.2.v20151217-774c696):
>   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException Exception
>   Description: Trying to get value for instance variable [id] of type
>   [java.lang.Long] from the object
>   [jpa.test.minimalExample.SomeClass].  The specified object is not
>   an instance of the class or interface declaring the underlying field.
>   Internal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set
>   java.lang.Long field jpa.test.minimalExample.VImpl.id to
>   jpa.test.minimalExample.SomeClass Mapping:
>   org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DirectToFieldMapping[id-->VIMPL.ID]
>   Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(jpa.test.minimalExample.VImpl -->
>   [DatabaseTable(VIMPL)])

Any advice on how to fix annotations/rework my class structure in a way that makes persisting a map like this possible are greatly appreciated.I also would very much like to understand the error itself (and why its there) instead of only getting a workaround, although right now I'll get any help I can get.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I think SomeClass no need to be generic. change V source/target to VImpl and have a try

Comment: I had some problems with multiple manyToMany mappings to the same class, here that problem seems weird but have a look at your database table schemas.

Comment: @andy You are right, that actually works. It is not quite the solution I had hoped for (as I am extremely reluctant to hardcode types into an abstract base class), put perhaps I can do something like `TypedAbstractClass extends MyGenericAbstractClass` and override all methods that involve `SomeClass<V>`using some typed version of it.
I still would like to know what WHY this error occurs though :(